# How to troubleshoot .net application on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, .net-framework, windows-8.1-upgrade

This is my scenario, i have a third party application that is writen on .net 2003 ( i dont have te source code), it was running happily on windows 8 , then windows 8.1 update came on and now it wont start.

I ran the app with  these compatibility settings:

- Compatibility mode Windows XP SP 3
- Run as Administrator
- Low color resolution

I have tried:

- Removing then reinstalling the application
- Runing it from the command line ( as administrator ) -> no output
- Check the windows logs -> nothing related to the app or .net
- Also from the control panel -> windows features -> .net framework, un install and install, still no luck.

What else can i do in order to at least see why it wont start?

Comment: VS2003 = .net 1.1 which is no longer supported since Windows 7. So you had luck to use it in Windows 8.

Comment: Does it need a *particular version* of the .NET Framework? On my 8.1 PC, I find only v. 4.5 is still installed. In the Control Panel applet *Programs and Features*, search on *.NET*. Deprecated versions can be downloaded from MS, e.g. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21 for v. 3.5.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, magicandre1981 gona try resinstalling .net 3.5 using the link of DrMoishe Pippik, and see it it works =(